# React js - setState and array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, so I'm struggling with this:

**why does setting state as a single object array works, but getting the array from state, pushing to it, and setting as state again doesn't work?**

This is the working code. I have this IMAGE array in as state, not initialized:

```
class PersonalBananas extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            username: 0,
            images: 0,
            pred: 0,
            IMAGES: 0
        }
        this.imgList = this.imgList.bind(this)
    }
```

In componentDidMount I call the imgList():

```
    componentDidMount() {
        let $this = this;

        axios.get('http://localhost:8081/auth/username')
            .then((response) => {
                let uname = response.data;
                this.setState({
                    username: uname
                });
            })

        axios.get('http://localhost:8081/auth/files')
            .then((response) => {
                let imgs = response.data;
                console.log("images response: "+imgs);
                this.setState({
                    images: imgs
                },
                    function() { $this.imgList() }
                );
            })
    }
```

Inside imgList() I call getImgPred:

```
imgList = () => {
        var $this = this;
        const IMAGES = [];
        const imgpaths = this.state.images;
        console.log("images from imgLis():"+imgpaths);

        for (let i = 0; i < imgpaths.length; i++) {
            var path = imgpaths[i]
            this.getImgPred(path);
            console.log("pred:"+$this.state.pred);
        }
        console.log("IMAGES from imgLis():"+IMAGES);
    };
```

And here finally I call the IMAGESpush():

```
    getImgPred = (path) => {
        var username = this.state.username;
        var $this = this;

        let regex = new RegExp(username+'\/(.*?)$');
        let imgRegex= /{username}\/(.*?)$/;

        let filename = regex.exec(path);
        console.log("filename at front:"+filename[1]);
        console.log("regex1:"+imgRegex+", regex2:"+regex);

        axios.post('http://localhost:8081/auth/imgpred',
            "filename=" + filename[1]
        ).then(function (response) {
            console.log("response at front (get img prediction):"+response.data);
            if (response.status === 200) {
                $this.setState({
                    pred: response.data
                }, function() { $this.IMAGESpush(path) } );
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the problem: **when I just initialize the const IMAGES = [], push to it, then set state - it works fine. What i'm trying to do is: const Images = this.state.IMAGES.** I can't do it.

```
    IMAGESpush = (path) => {
        var $this = this;
        const IMAGES = [];
        IMAGES.push({
            src: process.env.PUBLIC_URL +`/${path}`,
            thumbnail: process.env.PUBLIC_URL +`/${path}`,
            thumbnailWidth: 320,
            thumbnailHeight: 320,
            caption: $this.state.pred
        })
        this.setState({
            IMAGES: IMAGES
        })
    }



    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <Gallery images={this.state.IMAGES}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PersonalBananas;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pushing to an array does not change its reference, it's essentially the same object to React's reconciliation algorithm (which doesn't deeply compare objects inside of its state).

What you should really do is creating a new array, expanding the old one into it and adding a new element on top of that. Like this:

```js
this.setState({
    IMAGES: [...this.state.IMAGES, { /* new object here */ }]
});
```

You can also use the `concat` function to merge arrays, since it doesn't change any array - it returns a new array instead.

```js
this.setState({
    IMAGES: this.state.IMAGES.concat([{ /* new object here */ }])
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! (somehow I always figure out the way the same moment first answer to my stackoverflow question appears...)